# Display hierarchical, multidimensional array as a nested list (recursion)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am faced with this challenge:

I need to display data from a hierarchical, multi-dimensional array as a nested list. I want to use recursion to do it as I do not know how many levels the list might have. This is the data I am working on (simplified):

```
array (size=54)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[786]
      public 'term_id' => string '1' (length=3)
      public 'name' => string 'All' (length=25)
      public 'parent' => string '0' (length=3)
      public 'children' => array (size=2)
            0 => 
                object(stdClass)[785]
                  public 'term_id' => string '2' (length=3)
                  public 'name' => string 'Clothes' (length=25)
                  public 'parent' => string '1' (length=3)
                  public 'children' => (size=1)
                      0 => 
                        object(stdClass)[786]
                          public 'term_id' => string '3' (length=3)
                          public 'name' => string 'Scarves' (length=25)
                          public 'parent' => string '2' (length=3)
            1 =>
                object(stdClass)[785]
                  public 'term_id' => string '4' (length=3)
                  public 'name' => string 'Gloves' (length=25)
                  public 'parent' => string '1' (length=3)
```

The result should be something a nested list similar to this one:

- All

  - Clothes

    - Scarves
  - Food

    - Vegetables

After trying many time, I've built utilized `array_walk_recursive` and another recursive function of my own (simplified):

```
function attachChildren($items)
{
    foreach($items as $item) {
        echo $item->name;
        if (is_array(($item->children))) {
            $this->attachChildren($item->children);
        }
    }
}

function buildTree($value, $key)
{
    echo $value->name;
    if (is_array($value->children)) {
        $this->attachChildren($value->children);
    }           
}

array_walk_recursive($sortedArray, 'buildTree');
```

The problem with this solution is getting the formatting right. Two functions produce output and I find it difficult to arrange the items in an indented list.

What is the best way to have this array displayed as an indented list with multiple levels?

Comment: walk through array and sub array. first index element `ul` sub array `li` sub array append `ul>li`

Answer (score 1):

```
function walk($array){  
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "<ul>";
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<li>{$value['name']}</li>";

            walk($value);
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

$ar = [
        ['name' => 'All', ['name' => 'Clothes', ['name' =>'Scarves']]],
        ['name' => 'Gloves']
      ];

walk($ar);
```